# "Run across two axes" vs. "run on two axes"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which one of the following is correct?

> - Cricket chauvinism runs across two axes, those of nation and generation.
> - Cricket chauvinism runs on two axes, those of nation and generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither; even metaphorically, things don't "run across" or "run on" axes, they generally either "run along" axes or "revolve around", "revolve on", "turn around" or "turn on" axes.

[Here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runs+on+the+axis%2Cruns+across+the+axis%2Cruns+along+the+axis%2Crevolves+around+the+axis%2Crevolves+on+the+axis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=6) is a Google Ngram showing that "revolve around", "revolve on", and "run along" are all used, but that "run on" and "run across" are rare.

Comment: ...or run along them.

Comment: @Brett; yes, "runs along two axes" is undoubtedly the preposition the OP was looking for.

Comment: It's worth noting that 3 of the 7 instances of "**runs across two axes**" in Google Books are OP's quoted reference. The sensible choice, "**runs along two axes**" seems to have about 16 distinct citations. @Peter - why don't you add that to your answer text and save yourself some downvotes?

Comment: It's interesting that without the expected "runs along" I immediately interpreted "runs across" to mean "happens upon" and "axes" to mean the tools used to chop down trees- and then had the hardest time trying to make sense of the sentence.  I might also suggest that "varies along" is common when discussing the range and domain of functions.